# Windows 10 netflix app not working properly with 1366x768 resolution

Tags: windows-10, netflix

I have the netflix app on windows 10 and it keeps on going black frequently. If I reduce my PC resolution to 1360x768 then it seems to work just fine.
[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ubXz-7seQPc3o3alQ1Zk5fRlE/view?usp=sharing) is what happens

This problem happens only on the netflix app and microsoft edge. Someone please help!!

Comment: Have you tried a different browser such Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox?

Comment: It works fine with chrome and other browsers, however only edge browser, windows app and internet explorer get 1080p, the maximum any other browser could get is 720p. That's the reason I'd prefer using edge.

Comment: I would mention that the difference shouldn't be that noticeable at 720p on a small laptop screen compared to say a TV

Answer (score 0):

It could be a connection issue: "If you get a black screen when you attempt to play a movie or TV show on your TV or Blu-ray player, you may be experiencing an issue with your Internet connection. Follow the troubleshooting steps below to resolve the issue." - https://help.netflix.com/en/node/25891

or Silverlight https://help.netflix.com/en/node/95

or maybe a problem with your drivers which may need to be updated or uninstalled: and reinstalled

> yone caldwell said:
>
> I ran CCleaner and uninstalled the old catalyst. went into the device
> manager and removed the driver (radeon 7770) reboot into safe mode and
> downloaded the latest beta catalyst driver (12.11) and reinstalled it.
> no problems so far. I will report back if anything happens.
>
> ...
>
> Yeah it completely fixed the problem. But you have to use CCLEANER it
> will remove everything from the old driver which causes the problem.
> And update to the latest catalyst.

from: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/MSxmc-HVVl4/3P8L50kfFSMJ

As for maximum 720p in any other browsers, this does appear to be a current limitation http://www.pcworld.com/article/3095259/browsers/confirmed-only-microsoft-edge-will-play-netflix-content-at-1080p-on-your-pc.html